# get only one kind of response pdo php

Tags: php, pdo

I'm doing pdo request to get data from my database

```
public function getAll(){
    $req = $this->_bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM '.$this->_table);
    $req->execute();
    return $req->fetchAll();
}
```

But I get duplicate answers

for exemple if I do a foreach I have

```
$value[0] = 1;
$value['id'] = 1;
$value[1] = 'Ant';
$value['login'] = 'Ant';
$value[2] = 'aa@aa.aa';
$value['mail'] = 'aa@aa.aa';
```

I'd like to just have

```
$value['id'] = 1;
$value['login'] = 'Ant';
$value['mail'] = 'aa@aa.aa';
```

Thanks

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change your code to...

```
   return $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

to return the results as associative arrays only.